# How to run job-to-job linking in multi-project pipelines on GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

Example:

I have 3 different pipelines (projects) in GitLab.
Each pipeline has multiple jobs, each targeting a different remote VM and set a different GitLab CI environment.
The jobs are all manually triggered (currently).
What I am trying to achieve is a linking (multi-project) pipeline that runs like this:
Once I trigger job "X" in the pipeline #1, upon succeeding, that will trigger **ONLY** job "X" in the pipeline #2 which then again, upon success, will trigger **ONLY** job "X" in pipeline #3.

By job "X" I mean a job that runs on a certain remote VM, I don't want the entire pipeline to run since I don't want to change all targets. All examples I found only work at a pipeline level, not at the job level. What am I missing?

PS: I'm new to the GitLab CI scene so please forgive my lack of understanding in case there's an easy solution that I've missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible yes. If I take your example, in job "X" from pipeline 1, you can trigger a pipeline from another project using [Gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#triggering-a-pipeline) :

```
script:
  - "curl --request POST --form token=TOKEN --form ref=master https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/9/trigger/pipeline"
```

To ensure triggering only job "X" from pipeline 2, add use `only` keyword with `api` [condition](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic) :

```
job_X:
  only:
    - api
```

Comment: Thanks! Been struggling with this for quite a while now :)

Comment: Quick question, where does the value of "TOKEN" come from?

Comment: it's a [personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) you can generate in your user settings

Comment: I was not able to trigger a pipeline with a pesonal token. I was getting 404 and this is apparently documented [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#404-not-found-when-triggering-a-pipeline). TOKEN must be a trigger token